# How to wire an old single phase AC brushed motor to be reversable

Tags: motor, ac, reverse-polarity, universal-motor

I have searched several forums and found a lot of interesting stuff, but nothing yet that really applies to my situation.  I have an old Westinghouse FH motor 1 1/2HP single phase brushed AC motor.  There are four wires coming out of it.  The wires are labeled T1, T2, T3, and T4.  It is currently being used as a motor for a lathe.  The T1 and T2 wires are joined together.  And the T3 and T4 wires are joined together.  I have the leads connected to a drum switch, but no matter what polarity is provided the Motor always spins one direction CCW.  I don't see how reversing the polarity doesn't cause the direction to change.  It doesn't appear to have a capacitor.  I inherited the motor wired in this condition and have poked around on it a bit with swapping leads and other stuff but cant get it to run in any other configuration.  Any knowledge is appreciated.

[image: Wires]
[image: Motor Plate]

Comment: A photo of the motor and wiring would be useful. If there are brushes then let us see them. "*I don't see how reversing the polarity doesn't cause the direction to change.*" The mains does that for you 50 or 60 times a second without you doing anything.

Comment: You first need to determine what kind of motor it is. Since you have said that it is brushed, why have you applied the [brushless-dc-motor] tag? It seems likely the motor is a universal motor. That would have a commutator. There are also motors with slip-rings, wound-rotor induction motors. There are also repulsion motors that have commutators. A universal motor can be reversed by reversing the rotor connection with respect to the stator. The motor may need to be taken apart for access to do that.

Comment: Is there a nameplate on the motor?

Comment: Ill get some better photos tomorrow.  For now this is the best one I have.  I will have to do some research as well to determine what type it is.  Thank you both.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/9QcytpS

Comment: The 1725 RPM rating on the nameplate makes me believe that the motor is some type of induction motor. If it has a commutator, it could be a repulsion-start induction motor. If that is the case, it might be possible to reverse it by changing the brush position.

Comment: Information that I have indicates that repulsion motors can be modified to operate in the opposite direction by re-positioning the brushes. In the repulsion motor that I have, that requires partly disassembling the motor. I would expect that many other repulsion motors would be similar. Here are photos of the motor I have. https://photos.app.goo.gl/pKmZFDdMEt7wPJrH7

Answer (score 5):

Old Westinghouse Type FR motors were what is called an Induction / Repulsion motor, a very early type that is now no longer made because Capacitor Start motors are simpler and easier (and reversible). Yours probably dates back to the 1920s or 30s, maybe the 40s pre-WWII, but not younger than that. The brushes are used in acceleration only by creating repulsion with the stator windings, but are moved out of the way via a centrifugal mechanism as the motor speeds up. The video below shows the basic concept, albeit in an earlier form where the brushes were moved manually.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KdaipeodLo

The thing about those motors was, they are not reversible. Sorry.

Comment: Note 10-8-36 is stamped on the nameplate just below and to the right of the top rivet.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration from the schematic 'A' and it should do the trick.  Good Luck! KB[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure out the wiring in the end?
Going on the image above, you might be able to separate the joined wires and connect them to the other side. This might work.
Check the resistance on them to find out the main winding.